# How to use variables from another file in python?

Tags: python, python-import

I have created two files. The first one called **EA** contains variables and calls to functions. The second file called **EA_Functions** contains all the functions used in **EA**.

This is **EA**:

```
from EA_Functions import *

HIGHEST_NUMBER = 10
LOWEST_NUMBER = 1
SET_SIZE = 5
NUMBER_OF_PARENTS = 2
NUMBER_OF_CHILDREN = 2
MUTATION_STEP_SIZE = 0.5

warms = {}

# Create an initial random sets of warms
for i in range(SET_SIZE):
    warms[i] = np.random.randint(low=LOWEST_NUMBER, high=HIGHEST_NUMBER + 1, size=SET_SIZE, dtype=int)

# Order the set of warms based on the error
warms_sorted = sort(warms)
```

This is **EA_Functions**:

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint


def calculate_error(lst):
    return (SET_SIZE - np.mean(lst)) ** 2


def sort(dictionary):
    return sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: calculate_error(item[1]))
```

I want to use **SET_SIZE** variable contained in the first file, **EA**.

If in **EA_Functions** I try to import **EA**:

```
from EA import *
```

I get errors during the execution of the "main" code, the file **EA**

Comment: You need to make it a function parameter.

Comment: Why do you need to have it on EA? If you are not going to change it's value via code, you can have it on EA_Functions and the code will do fine

Comment: You should include the error message in the question.

Comment: Some variables are also used on EA

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you need to use the same variables in two files then you could save variables  in separated file `FA_CONSTANSTS.py` and use `from FA_CONSTANSTS import *` in `EA` and `EA_Functions`. But still it could be better to use them as arguments in functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a parameter in the function like this:

```
def calculate_error(lst, size):
    return (size - np.mean(lst)) ** 2
```

then, when you call it pass SET_SIZE to calculate_error()

Comment: Very smart! Thank you ;) I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting errors because you have a circular import. If you are from `EA_Functions.py` in `EA.py`, you shouldn't import from `EA.py` in `EA_Functions.py`.